# Create a new table based on another two tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, compare, create-table

Create a new table based on another two tables in SQL. The first table USER has one variable

```
user_id     | purchase_time  
-----------------------------
Marta       | 10/20/2019             
Steve       | 10/21/2019            
Michael     | 10/18/2019
```

And COUPON table has two variables

```
user_id     | coupon_id        | coupon_time 
-------------------------------------------
Marta       | 12345            | 10/21/2019 
Steve       | 12356            | 10/18/2019 
Marta       | 12365            | 10/01/2019 
Michael     |                  |
```

The problem is to create a new table USER_SUMMARY. Count the numbers of coupons received before and after purchase_time, and count the total coupons received. If no coupon received after puchase_time, count 0. The final created a table should like below:

```
user_id     | purchase_before_coupon        | purchase_after coupon    | total_coupons 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Marta       | 1                             | 1                        | 2                        
Steve       | 0                             | 1                        | 1
Michael     | 0                             | 0                        | 0
```

Should not be complicated if done in Python or R, but I don't quite know how to do it in SQL syntax. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`CREATE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) query to generate the `user_summary` table. The `SELECT` query counts how many purchases were made before or after each coupon for each user, as well as counting the total number of their coupons:

```
CREATE TABLE user_summary AS
SELECT u.user_id, 
       COALESCE(SUM(u.purchase_time < c.coupon_time), 0) AS purchase_before,
       COALESCE(SUM(u.purchase_time >= c.coupon_time), 0) AS purchase_after,
       COUNT(c.coupon_id) AS total
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN coupon c ON c.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Output (of `SELECT * FROM user_summary`) after running this query:

```
user_id     purchase_before     purchase_after  total
Marta       1                   1               2
Michael     0                   0               0
Steve       0                   1               1
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dLHqUwuBv5da4xq4FDesTf/0)

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I want1